# Jquery class/object creation and a slight issue. Curious why "new" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two requests, if I may.

1. Least important but would love your opinions in regards to my code below. Any way to improve it. Make it more portable/robust etc?
2. It seems when create a "New" the code doesn't fully work. My guess is I am not really creating a valid object. What am I doing wrong.

This didn't work in trying to create a new object.

```
var ll_port2 = New ll_port;
    ll_port2.init({'aa':'#_div1','bb':'#_div2','cc':'1000'}); <-- no work
```

if I never make a new item, it works, ala:

```
ll_port.init({'aa':'#_div1','bb':'#_div2','cc':'1000'});  <-- works
```

Code below:

```
           var ll_port = {
                   items:{
                       outside: /billabong|newage/,
                    },
                   assign: function(){
                       ccont = this.items.aa;
                       if (typeof $(ccont) === 'object' && $(ccont).css('z-index') && $(ccont).css('z-index') != this.items.cc) {
                              $(ccont).css('zIndex','').css('zIndex', this.items.zi);
                       }
                   },
                   closeit:function(){
                       if($(this.items.bb).length && $(this.items.bb).is(':visible')){
                           $(this.items.bb).hide();
                       }
                   },
                   strL: function(){
                       var _self = this;
                         $("body :not(" + _self.items.aa + ")")
                             .mousedown(function(event){
                                  event.stopPropagation();
                                  _self.closeit();
                                  _self.assign();
                              });
                        $('iframe').live('mouseover', 
                            function () {
                                if(_self.items.outside.test($(this).attr('src'))){
                                  _self.closeit();
                                }
                            });​
                  },
                  init: function(data){
                      $.extend(this.items, data);
                      this.strL();
                      var _self = this;
                      setTimeout(function(){
                          _self.assign();
                      }, 1500);
                  }
           }; 
            ll_port.init({'aa':'#_div1','bb':'#_div2','cc':'1000'});
```

Comment: `ll_port` is not a constructor function. You can't use `new` with it.

Answer (score 2):

`New` (beside of the typo, which should be `new`) should be only used on `function`s not on objects.

And those functions *should* be constructors.

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `ll_port` a function, not an object.

```
var ll_port = function(){
    //... all your stuff
    this.items = {outside: /billabong|newage/};
}
```

Then you can use `var ll_port2 = new ll_port()`

See here for more info on [Object Oriented Programming with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)